# Book where alien helmet makes people smarter?

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I remember reading book a while ago (maybe about 20 years) about a boy who decides to wear a helmet that he stole from his teacher, who happens to be an alien. This helmet makes him much smarter and allows his mind to also pick up TV and radio frequencies, which almost drove him insane. His alien teacher then kidnaps him and recruits him for a new mission. I believe the book was part of a children’s series. **What is the name of this book?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is ***[My Teacher Fried My Brains](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1030670.My_Teacher_Fried_My_Brains)*** (1991) by Bruce Coville, the second book in the *[My Teacher Is an Alien](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57743-my-teacher-is-an-alien)* series.

From Goodreads:

> Brains are sizzling in the seventh grade...
>
> The first day of seventh grade is probably the worst day of Duncan Dougal's life. He knows that things are really bad when he finds an alien's hand in a Dumpster and then gets plugged into an alien brain fryer!
>
> Can Duncan find out which of the four new teachers in his school is an alien before his brains get fried to a pulp -- or before the aliens try to fry the whole planet?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Teacher_Is_an_Alien):

> Three months later, in *My Teacher Fried My Brains*, former bully Duncan Dougal discovers an alien's human disguise in the form of a human skin-like glove in a dumpster, which leads him to believe that there is still another alien posing as someone else at the school. While investigating, Duncan participates in an in-class demonstration of static electricity that he comes to believe has made him more intelligent. Since he believes this machine is making him more intelligent, he sneaks into his science classroom after school hours to use it. He gradually becomes a much more thoughtful and considerate person. One day when he is using the machine he discovers an alien creature “Poot” in the classroom refrigerator, which makes him even more suspicious of his science teacher.
>
> One day after school when Duncan was having a terrible day, he goes into his home economics teacher Miss Betty Lou Karpou's classroom to seek advice. During this conversation, Miss Karpou is revealed to be the alien and identifies herself as Kreeblim. She freezes Duncan's body and uses his brain as a means of communication among other aliens in the galaxy who are trying to decide what they want to do with humans. Susan, the hero of the previous story, tries to save Duncan when Kreeblim is out of her house, however the two of them do not get out of the house in time.
>
> At the end of the book, Peter (with enhanced eyesight and no need of glasses) and Broxholm return, and Duncan and Susan decide to help Peter prove to the Interplanetary Council, the ruling aliens of the galaxy, that the human race is worth saving.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Where did you find it?

Comment: I Googled the term "children's book boy teacher helmet smarter". One of the results included the phrase "he dons a helmet that fries his brains, but makes him smarter" beneath the link. I then Googled that phrase, and _My Teacher Fried My Brains_ was the top result.